# How can I get TeXPortal working on Android 7?

Tags: pdftex, android

TeXPortal works fine on Android 6 but will not compile or update itself automatically on Android 7. Has anyone been able to make it work? Is the source code available so we can try to make it work? Are there alternatives to TeXPortal that are as easy to use on mobile devices and tablets?

Answer (score 2):

You can install TeXlive through the Linux terminal emulator app [Termux](https://termux.com). The app is available for Android 5.0 or higher and it does not require rooting your device. After installation the Termux app, you can install TeXlive LaTeX software as on a normal Linux distribution, so you will be able to create tex files using editors such as vim or emacs, and compile them.